# Image classification convolutional neural networks

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem by using a convolutional NN to classify an image data set to check the type of disease it is. I have reached task 1b and trying to implement the training loop. However, I am getting an error and can't understand how to implement the training loop.

I am sharing the google drive link.

The code in task 1b where I am getting an error:

```
#                     news headlines text and its corresponding label.
#                   - sentence_len the maximum sentence length you want the
#                     tokenized to return. Any sentence longer than that should
#                     be truncated by the tokenizer. Any shorter sentence should
#                     padded by the tokenizer.
#                We will be using the pretrained 'distilbert-base-uncased' transform,
#                so please use the appropriate tokenizer for it. NOTE: You will need
#                to include the relevant import statement.
```

I am stuck at this part. Can anyone suggest how to implement it?

Comment: Please notice that cross-posting [verbatim questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638482/image-classification-problem-using-convolutional-neural-networks) to multiple SE sites is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__getitem__` method you should return both the image and the label, in your current example you are trying to get the image by indexing the `img_dir` variable or your class, which won't work since this is of type `Path`. The general steps for the `__getitem__` method is that you should (1) get the path of image, (2) load the image and (3) convert the image to a tensor for pytorch to use. This would something like this:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

class LesionDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_dir, labels_fname):
        self.img_dir = Path(img_dir)
        self.img_paths = self.img_dir.glob("*")
        self.labels_fname = pd.read_csv(labels_fname)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels_fname)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = self.img_paths[idx]
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
        label = self.labels_fname[idx]
        return image, label
```